# Locus of roots of all convex combinations of two monic polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, zeroes

Let $p,q$ be monic polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[t]$ and for $\alpha \in [0,1]$, let $c_\alpha := \alpha p + (1-\alpha)q \in \mathbb{C}[t]$. Since the roots of a polynomial vary continuously with respect to its coefficients, following the fundamental theorem of algebra, the locus 
$$ L(p,q) := \{ z \in \mathbb{C}\mid c_\alpha(z)=0,~\alpha\in[0,1]\} $$
consists of $n$ (not necessarily distinct) continuous paths.

*A priori* determination of the endpoints of the paths is ostensiblty diffcult, but experimental evidence suggests the following.

**Conjecture.** Let $P = \{ \lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\}$ and $Q=\{\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n\}$ denote the roots of $p$ and $q$, respectively. For $1 \leq i,j\leq n$, let $d(i,j):= |\lambda_i- \mu_j|$. If 
$$\text{argmin}_{(i,j)}(d) =\{(k,\ell)\},$$ 
then there is a path from $\mu_\ell$ to $\lambda_k$.

I am interested in knowing whether the above conjecture is known or if it can be established from what is known from complex analysis and the geometry of polynomials. Note that it is not clear what happens when there is a tie.

Notice that if $p$ and $q$ share a simple root $\lambda$, then there is a (degenerate) path from that root to itself (this corresponds to the case when the distance is zero). The picture below contains a typical example [image: Locus of Roots for $n=5$.] generated from the following `MATLAB` code

```
p=[1 randn(1,5)+i*randn(1,5)]
q=[1 randn(1,5)+i*randn(1,5)]
hold on
scatter(real(roots(p)),imag(roots(p)),'x','r')
scatter(real(roots(q)),imag(roots(q)),'o','b')
for k=0:.01:1
c=k*p+(1-k)*q;
scatter(real(roots(c)),imag(roots(c)),'.','m');
end
```

**Update:** Per Christian's answer below, the conjecture, as stated above, is not true; however, I am still interested in *a priori* determination of the paths (new question [posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291858/locus-of-roots-of-all-convex-combinations-of-two-monic-polynomials-ii)).

Comment: I wonder what will happen to polynomials of different degrees...

Comment: @??? Polynomials of different degree can be considered by roots appearing /existing 'at infinity'.

Comment: May I suggest that you accept Christian's answer to your original question, and post this variation as a new question (with links at each question to the other one)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Done! And thank you for the helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not true. Take $p=z^2-z$, $q=(z+0.1)^2-0.2^2$. Then the zeros of $p$ are at $0,1$, those of $q$ are at $-0.3,0.1$, so the smallest distance is between $0.1$ and $0$. However, $0.1$ moves towards $1$, not $0$ (as one would in fact expect from a picture).

Comment: Perhaps it's true with the added assumption that both polynomials contain nonreal roots.

Comment: @PietroPaparella: I don't think that will help, you can do a small perturbation of this example that moves the zeros into the complex plane.

Comment: In your example, the roots of both polynomials are collinear -- I'm wondering if excluding this case will make the conjecture true.

Comment: @PietroPaparella: I think this has the same answer as in my previous comment, this property is not essential, and a small perturbation will remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the truth of the conjecture is (well, Christian's answer tells us...) the zeros of linear combinations of polynomials have been studied, see for example:

On the zeros of a linear combination of polynomials (Pacific Journal, 1966m Robert Vermes).

Comment: I've read that paper; unfortunately, it does not address the issue I raise above of a priori determination of the paths.